# Can not execute php code in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

WAMP was successfully installed and all was working fine. But no php files can be run inside the *www* directory. I even restart it several times...

my php file with file name *test.php* inside the directory *www/myphp* was

`<? php
echo "Testing PHP";
?>`

Hope you good guys can help me. And thanks in advance....

Comment: Check the Apache configuration.  The PHP module must be loaded, file *.php must be defined as being intepreted by PHP, permissions,...  Do you have logs (access and error)?

Comment: Follow a better tutorial? (and actually read it step by step .. skipping does not make you smart)

Comment: May it be a typo in your question but if your code is exactly same as what is here, you should fix `<? php` to `<?php` on begin of the file. I think your displaying error is off and you have a syntax error.